# How to implement block link inside span tag?

Tags: html, css, block

I've read how to implement block link from this source: http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=74
However, I don't know how to apply it to  tag located inside  tag. As my html code is following this format:

```
<li class="">
    <span>
        <strong>
           <a href="#">Text</a>
        </strong>
        <span class="Count">Number</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Why can't you just wrap the `<a>` tag around the outermost `<span>`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code from the linked example should work with your example code as well, I think.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Why do you need the link to be block-level? Maybe some CSS would help, or a complete jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

A `<span>` is an inline element, so it should not contain a block link. This is because inline elements should never contain block elements. Try this HTML (removed `<span>`):

```
<li class="myList">
    <strong>
       <a href="#">Text</a>
    </strong>
    <span class="Count">Number</span>
</li>
```

And CSS:

```
li.myList strong a { display:block; }
```

If anything there looks confusing, you might want to do some reading of "CSS selectors" and "inline and block elements in css".

Comment: Additionally, you could probably remove the `<strong>` tag and replace it with `font-weight: bold` in the CSS, since it's doubtful that the link in this instance is meant to carry the semantic emphasis defined in the spec ( http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-strong-element ).